# When I wnat to get package flutter it show me HTTP error 403: Forbidden

Tags: android, http, flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am working on flutter project in Intellij Idea. when I want to add a package in pubspec.yaml, it leads to below errror:

```
HTTP error 403: Forbidden


package:pub/src/http.dart 218:5                 _ThrowingClient.send
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart 33:31  ThrottleClient.send
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 322:37       BoundHostedSource._download
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 217:13       BoundHostedSource.downloadToSystemCache
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 374:48          Entrypoint._get.<fn>

===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                      runZoned
package:pub/src/http.dart 272:10                withDependencyType
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 370:12          Entrypoint._get
dart:async                                      Future.wait
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 231:18          Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
dart:async                                      _completeOnAsyncReturn
package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart      VersionSolver.solve
dart:async                                      _completeOnAsyncReturn
package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart      VersionSolver._result
This is an unexpected error. Please run

pub --trace '--verbosity=warning' get --no-precompile

and include the logs in an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/new
```

I have tried using vpn and without vpn both of them doesnt work.
Also, when i add some common package such as provider or http, its fine.

This is my code:

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
     sdk: flutter
 flutter_localizations:
     sdk: flutter

 provider: ^3.2.0
 http: ^0.12.0+2
 font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
 flutter_rating_bar: ^3.0.0
```

my flutter sdk version :
flutter_windows_v1.9.1+hotfix.6-stable_3

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy or using the Chinese community mirror?

Comment: @Nuts Im from Iran. I tested with vpn and without vpn. I think if there is corporate proxy, this vpn can solve it. Is it true?

Comment: Not always: VPNs themselves can be blocked in firewalls. Please check this out: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall

Comment: I test the solution in this link but it doesnt work for me. @Nuts

Answer (score 4):

same problem happened for me
so i just did

1:flutter clean

2:use 2 vpn at same time

this problem happened because of your connection ;)

Answer (score 0):

use proxy or vpn
your ip address is block
https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall

Answer (score 0):

It may solve your problem:

1. add **".catch-pub"** folder in your current project
2. add global environment variable **"PUB_HOSTED_URL"** with value **"https://pub.dev/"**

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and changed a few **VPN**, but it was still a problem and did not work

I used a service that **changed DNS** to fix the problem of sanctions and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to solve this problem, I finally found a solution.

First, you have to delete all the packages of project from **pubspec.yaml** file (you can comment these lines, so you don't forget what's packages used)

then add all the packages to the project from **cmd** with this command:

```
flutter pub add <package_name>
```

**Make sure to use cmd, not powershell.**

I hope this solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It often related to VPN connection. before running `flutter pub get`, being sure that you can open `https://developer.android.com/` site.